# How to sort a Numbers table using Javascript for Automation

Tags: javascript-automation

I want to sort a Numbers table using Javascript for Automation, the code like

```
table.sort(table.columns["P"], {direction: "descending"})
```

But the Script Editor told me: Parameter is missing. (-1701)

[image: the sort method]

Here is the code I wrote:

```
 var Numbers = Application("Numbers")
 var path = Path("/Volumes/sfufoet/test.numbers")

 var doc = Numbers.open(path)

 var sheet = doc.sheets[1]
 var table = sheet.tables[1]

 table.sort(table.columns["P"], {direction: "descending"})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found it!

the right code is:

```
table.sort({by:table.columns["P"], direction: "descending"})
```